# Spring 4 not automatically qualifying generic types on autowire

Tags: java, spring, generics, dependency-injection, spring-4

**PROBLEM HAS BEEN IDENTIFIED, POST UPDATED** (Scroll to bottom)

I am developing a desktop application currently using Spring (`spring-context`, `4.1.6.RELEASE`) for IoC and dependency injection. I am using an annotation configuration, using `@ComponentScan`. The issue I am experiencing is supposed to be implemented as a feature in `4.X.X`, as it states [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9965) and [here](http://www.jayway.com/2013/11/03/spring-and-autowiring-of-generic-types/), but I am getting the old `3.X.X` exception.

I have a parameterised interface that represents a generic repository:

```
public interface DomainRepository<T> {

    T add(T entity) throws ServiceException, IllegalArgumentException;

    // ...etc

}
```

I then have two concrete implementations of this, `ChunkRepositoryImpl` and `ProjectRepositoryImpl`, which are parameterised accordingly. They share some common implementation from an abstract class, but are declared like so:

```
@Repository
public class ChunkRepositoryImpl extends AbstractRepositoryImpl<Chunk> implements DomainRepository<Chunk> {

    // ...+ various method implementations

}

@Repository
public class ProjectRepositoryImpl extends AbstractRepositoryImpl<Project> implements DomainRepository<Project> {

    // ...+ various method implementations

}
```

My understanding of the above links leads me to believe that I should be able to autowire these without needing to manually specify the beans via `@Qualifier`. However, when I do so:

```
@Autowired
private DomainRepository<Project> repository;
```

I get the following exception (preceded by a long stack trace of course):

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.foo.bar.repositories.DomainRepository] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: chunkRepositoryImpl,projectRepositoryImpl

Can anybody shine a light as to why this might be happening? I would expect this exception in `3.X.X`, but it should not happen in `4.X.X`. What is the difference between my situation, and the one described [here](http://www.jayway.com/2013/11/03/spring-and-autowiring-of-generic-types/)?

**UPDATE**

I have discovered the source of the problem. One of the methods in my `DomainRepository<T>` interface is marked as `@Async`, and makes use of Spring's asynchronous capabilities. Removing this means that the beans are correctly qualified. I hypothesize that Spring transforms classes with `@Async` methods under the hood into some other class, and this process strips the type information, meaning that it can't tell the beans apart.

This means I now have two questions:

1. Is this intended behaviour?
2. Can anybody suggest a workaround?

[Here](https://github.com/wfaithfull/spring-async-type-erasure) is a project demonstrating the problem. Simply remove the `@Async` annotation from the `DomainRepository<T>` interface, and the problem dissappears.

Comment: This works fine for me on 4.x.x. Please post a complete and reproducible example.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Working on a reproducible example in a different project, but so far it is working for me as well. However, in the original project, the exception still persists. This is very confusing.

Comment: Is the name `Project` shadowed in the class with the `repository` field?

Comment: I wouldn't have thought of that, but sadly, no. The declaration in the class with the `repository` field is definitely referencing the same domain object as the repository declaration.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Eureka! I have discovered the source of the problem, although not the reason. One of the methods in my interface is marked `@Async`. Without this annotation, it works as expected. With, it fails with the above.

Comment: Can you provide an example now?

Comment: Yes. I will push a minimal project to GitHub and then edit this post with the link. [Here it is.](https://github.com/wfaithfull/spring-async-type-erasure)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I hypothesize that Spring transforms classes with @Async methods under
>   the hood into some other class, and this process strips the type
>   information, meaning that it can't tell the beans apart.

Yes. That's exactly what happens.

Spring 4 supports injecting beans by their full generic signature. Given the injection target

```
@Autowired
private DomainRepository<Project> repository;
```

and a bean **of type `ProjectRepositoryImpl`**, Spring will properly resolve and inject that bean into the field (or method argument, or constructor argument).

**However**, in your code, you don't actually have a bean of type `ProjectRepositoryImpl`, not even of type `DomainRepository<Project>`. You actually have a bean of type `java.lang.Proxy` (actually a dynamic subclass of it) that implements `DomainRepository`, `org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy`, and `org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised`.

With `@Async`, Spring needs to proxy your bean to add the asynchronous dispatching behavior. This proxy, by default, is a JDK proxy. JDK proxies can only inherit the interfaces of the target type. JDK proxies are produced with the factory method [`Proxy#newProxyInstance(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html#newProxyInstance-java.lang.ClassLoader-java.lang.Class:A-java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler-). Notice how it only accepts `Class` arguments, not `Type`. So it can only receive a type descriptor for `DomainRepository`, not for `DomainRepository<Chunk>`.

Therefore, you have no bean that implements your parameterized target type `DocumentRepository<Project>`. Spring will fall back to the raw type `DocumentRepository` and find two candidate beans. It's an ambiguous match so it fails.

The solution is to use CGLIB proxies with

```
@EnableAsync(proxyTargetClass = true)
```

CGLIB proxies allow Spring to get the full type information, not just interfaces. So your proxy will actually have a type that is a subtype of `ProjectRepositoryImpl`, for example, which carries with it the `DocumentRepository<Project>` type information.

---

A lot of the above are implementation details and defined in many separate places, [official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-async), [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Async.html), comments, etc. Use them carefully.